# Ошибка 500 и 404 в Djange

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, django

Сайт выдает при неправильном запросе или несуществующей странице ошибку **500**, иногда выдает **404**. А проблема в том, что нужно, чтобы выходила всегда ошибка 404. Прочитал о том, что ошибка 500 выпадает, если джанга не может найти 404.html, файл в templates, но ошибка 500 выходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настройте оповещения об ошибках (через [ADMINS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#admins) или лучше [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/)) и исправьте реальную причину 500 ошибки. Также можете посмотреть в логах (uwsgi, gunicorn, apache - зависит от способа запуска приложения у вас на сервере), или если ошибка стабильно повторяется и не в production, можно попробовать включить DEBUG.